# How to show binning of 7 days in fusiontime chart?

Tags: angular, fusioncharts

The requirement is to display weekly data in the fusion time graph. So we tried to use binning as follows:

```
binning:{
     "year": [],
     "month": [], 
     "day": [7],
     "hour": [],
     "minute": [],
     "second": [],
     "millisecond": [] 
}
```

But the allowed values for binning are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15 as mentioned in the Binning section of this link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-attributes.

How can we show the dates on the x axis with a gap of 7 days ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use 6 days binning as of now, weekly binning is not a natural distribution in the hierarchy of the time hence as of now it is not present in the libraray

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "a natural distribution in the hierarchy of the time"? A week seems very natural and commonplace.

Answer (score 2):

I have request weekly data binning. And they have an update in version 3.18 fusionchart and fusiontime 2.15

don't worry what you have to do is update to latest version.

```
binning: {
      year: [],
      month: [],
      day: [],
      week: [2],
      hour: [],
      minute: [],
      second: []
    }
```

Read more here:
https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/release-fusioncharts-3-18-fusiontime-2-6/

Answer (score 1):

Weekly bins are available in [fusiontime 2.6](https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/release-fusioncharts-3-18-fusiontime-2-6/?utm_source=Eloqua&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_content=weeklynewsletter100121)

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binning please refer [fusionTime](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/getting-started/change-default-aggregation#change-data-binning)